# Xamarin TapGestureRecognizer sometime does not work properly

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am currently building my mobile application using Xamarin.Forms and i encountered a problem (on both platform of ios and android) when i tried to use [Xamarin.Forms gestures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/) more particularly a [tap gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) on a xaml **Label**. Because i want to use this label as a link.

The problem is that this tab gesture that i used does **not work sometime** ( approximately 5 times test = 1 time bug).

During DEBUG when the problem occured i see that the tabbing is still recognized but it did not respond in the action i set up.

It occurs on both iOS and Android devices.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Image Source="icon_question" WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15"></Image>
    <Label Margin="15, -3, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           Text="Some text" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="15"  TextDecorations="Underline">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="_tabLinkForgetPassword"></TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
private void _tabLinkForgetPassword(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  App.Current.MainPage = new ResetPasswordPage(false);
}
```

I expect that the tab respond everytime, not just sometime like this. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Did you added NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  ?

Comment: @AndroDevil already tried and i am pretty sure that NumberOfTapsRequired is not relevant. thank you :D

Comment: I think you should provide tap recognizer to a layout surrounding your label. Otherwise you need to click exactly on label. Provide that click to relativelayout

Comment: @AndroDevil That solve the problem, only i have to adjust the size of the RelativeLayout to be properly fit to its components. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by AndroDevil,  you have to handle the tap gesture on a parent (a Grid, StackLayout, ContentView, whatever you want). in your case, why don't you use the Relative layout ? Thus, you can tap either the Label or the Image.

When you think it doesn't work, it is just that when you tap on the empty space : between characters (or even inside the void of a char like O (but admit it, kind of hard to tap on those few pixels)) of your text.

Last, you don't need to set NumberOfTapsRequired because as far as I remember, it is the default value.